# Timeout issue in protractor

Tags: protractor

My test case has executed successfully from the UI perspective, but still getting the error as below instead of saying giving the result as Passed.

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Could you please let me know what the reason may be.

**My conf file is as below:**

```
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['DMSE2E1.js'],
  framework: 'jasmine2',

  jasmineNodeOpts: { defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000 }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of the `DMSE2E1.js`?

Comment: its related to the project, i think from the security perspective i cannot publish the test case here :( Any other way to resolve the problem

Comment: Not that I can see. Your conf file looks fine, so the problem either is in the spec file, or someone else

Comment: are you manually declaring some functions with the `async` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

May be your scenario step is waiting to be notified for completing all lines in a scenario.

When using async/await

```
 it('Some test', async () => {

    await expect(homepg.getdata()).to.eventually.be.true

  });
```

When using callbacks

```
it('some text',(callback) => {
    expect(homepg.getdata()).to.eventually.be.true.and.notify(callback);
  });
```